# Chain rule derivatives matrix calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I am going through a proof which includes the following two statements about the first and second derivatives of a function f:

$\nabla f(Sy) = S^T \nabla f(Sy) \qquad \nabla^2f(Sy)=S^T \nabla^2 f(Sy)S$

Whereby f is a twice continuously differentiable function defined over $\mathbb{R}^n$
and $S: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an invertible map.

To me it is not totally clear which intermediate steps are needed to arrive at those final solutions, using the chain rule and properties of the inner product I would write the following:

$\begin{align}
\nabla f(Sy) &= \nabla f(Sy) \cdot S \\
&= S \cdot \nabla f(Sy) \\
&= S^T \nabla f(Sy)
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
\nabla^2f(Sy) &= S^T (\nabla^2  f(Sy)\cdot S) \\
&= S^T (\nabla^2  f(Sy)^T S) \\
&= S^T \nabla^2 f(Sy)S
\end{align}$

Maybe someone can confirm that this is in fact true or help me to get the true steps.

Comment: What *means* $\nabla f(Sy)$? $(\nabla(f\circ S))(y)$? And $S^T$? $S$ is a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you know the gradient $(g)$ and Hessian $(H)$ of a function in terms of the variable $x$
$$\eqalign{
 f = f(x),\,\,\,\,\,
 g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\,\,\,\,\,\,
 H = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
}$$
You are then told that $x$ is not independent, but actually depends another variable
$(x = Sy).\,\,$ Note that the matrix $S$ does not need to be invertible. It might even be **rectangular**.

Let's find the gradient $(p)$ and Hessian $(Q)$ with respect to this new variable, by way of differentials.
$$\eqalign{
df &= g:dx = g:(S\,dy) = (S^Tg):dy \cr
p &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = S^Tg \cr
\cr
dp &= S^T\,dg = S^T(H\,dx) = S^TH(S\,dy) \cr
Q &=\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} = S^THS \cr\cr
}$$